# PDO Presentation Suggestions?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to learn how to convert my queries to PDO. I finally got a simply row(count) query to work, and now I'm tackling more complex queries.

I'm currently using the following query. (Sorry it's so complex; I'm still working on simplifying it.)

```
$SeaURL = str_replace('Washington/', '', $MyURL);

$res = mysql_query ("SELECT P.URL, P.Title, P.Subtitle, P.MetaTitle, P.MetaDesc, P.KW, P.Live, PB.Common, PB.First, PB.Middle, PB.Last, PB.Prefix, PB.Suffix, PB.Born, PB.Died, PB.Birth_Place, PB.Death_Place, PB.Nationality, Brf.Site, Brf.Brief, PC.Class, PX.Article PXA, PX.Pagedex PXP, IVR.Article IVRA, IVR.Pagedex IVRP, SM.Article SMA, SM.Pagedex SMP
 FROM people P
 LEFT JOIN people_1_bio PB ON PB.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_1_class PC ON PC.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_briefs Brf ON Brf.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_articles_px PX ON PX.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_articles_ivr IVR ON IVR.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_articles_sm SM ON SM.URL = P.URL
 WHERE P.URL LIKE '$MyURL' AND P.Site = '$MySiteID'
 GROUP BY Class") or die (mysql_error());
```

With this particular query, I need a while loop to define some values, some of which I further put into arrays (e.g. $ClassList and $ClassLinked).

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($res))
{
 $URL = $row['URL'];
 $Title = $row['Title'];
 $Class = $row['Class'];
 $ClassList[] = $row['Class'];
 $ClassL = str_replace(' ', '_', $Class);
 $ClassLinked[] = '<a href="/People/'.$ClassL.'" title="'.$Class.'">'.$row['Class'].'</a>';
}
```

With the above data, I can display a page title (e.g. $Title = Carl Sagan) and a list (array) of classes he belongs to (e.g. $ClassList[] = scientist | writer | political activist).

---

Here's my PDO makeover:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'USERNAME','PASSWORD', $opt);

$SeaURL = str_replace('Washington/', '', $MyURL);

$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT P.URL, P.Title, P.Subtitle, P.MetaTitle, P.MetaDesc, P.KW, P.Live, PB.Common, PB.First, PB.Middle, PB.Last, PB.Prefix, PB.Suffix, PB.Born, PB.Died, PB.Birth_Place, PB.Death_Place, PB.Nationality, Brf.Site, Brf.Brief, PC.Class, PX.Article PXA, PX.Pagedex PXP, IVR.Article IVRA, IVR.Pagedex IVRP, SM.Article SMA, SM.Pagedex SMP
 FROM people P
 LEFT JOIN people_1_bio PB ON PB.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_1_class PC ON PC.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_briefs Brf ON Brf.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_articles_px PX ON PX.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_articles_ivr IVR ON IVR.URL = P.URL
 LEFT JOIN people_articles_sm SM ON SM.URL = P.URL
 WHERE P.URL LIKE '$MyURL' AND P.Site = '$MySiteID'
 GROUP BY Class");
$stm->execute();
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

---

I don't think my query is working, but it's hard to check it when I don't know how to display the results. That's what I'm asking about here.

If I understand the tutorial @ https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info correctly, the fetchAll() function replaces the while loop, right?

My original code defined the following values, which I could then echo in separate files:

```
$Class = $row['Class'];
$ClassList[] = $row['Class'];
```

What's the best way to define $Class and $ClassList using my new PDO script?

The page @ https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info offers a really confusing (and incomplete?) example using a foreach function...

```
?>
<table>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="news.php?<?=$row['id']?>">
        <?=htmlspecialchars($row['name'])?>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
```

But I'm not going to display all of my data in tables. And how do I define $Class as a single value but $ClassList as a series of values (array)?

Comment: `fetchAll()` does indeed replace the whole while loop. So in your case, you can place the entire body of your old `while` loop into `foreach ($data as $row)` to get the same result.

Comment: Since you're converting to PDO, you must start learning about parameters right away. You are using `prepare()/execute()` but getting none of the security benefit since you are still directly inserting variables `LIKE '$MyURL' AND P.Site = '$MySiteID'`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I'm confused. How do I put the body of a while loop into a foreach? Let's say, I want to display a value from the field $Title as the page title, and under that I want to list a series of classes: scientist | writer | political activist. Do I simply write the code <? foreach ($data as $row): ?> under my query, then, where I want my title to appear, write echo $row['Title']? I'd simply try it now, but my query isn't working yet. I haven't learned about parameters yet; I have so many things to fix before I get to that point.

Comment: I didn't see this because you didn't `@` me. Forget about the `foreach` example copied from the wiki page for now. What I'm saying is if you replace your old `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($res))` fetch loop with `foreach($data as $row)` you will end up with _exactly_ the same data structure you had in your old `mysql_*()` code, populating `$Title, $Class, $Classlist` etc, just as you had before. (Merely swap `while(...)` for `foreach(...)` and change nothing inside.

Comment: You should be using PDO's bindValue and not putting your PHP variables straight into the query string.

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski - One more question... It looks like a foreach function has to take the form of foreach ($array as $value). However, I can't figure out what values to substitute for $array and $value. I've tried various combinations from my query above, but nothing is working (unless my query itself isn't working correctly).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski his main problem is inefficient way of getting data. For sake of getting couple categories, he is looping over and over the same set of data to get only **one** set of variables. So there is no use for fetchAll(). Better let him to use regular while(fetch()).

Answer (score 0):

Use PDOStatement [fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) function. In your PDO makeover code, remove the line

```
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

use

```
while( $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) {
```

instead in the beginning of your loop to process the values.

There also is a better way to use `prepare()`

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare('SELECT P.URL, P.Title, P.Subtitle, P.MetaTitle, P.MetaDesc, P.KW, P.Live, PB.Common, PB.First, PB.Middle, PB.Last, PB.Prefix, PB.Suffix, PB.Born, PB.Died, PB.Birth_Place, PB.Death_Place, PB.Nationality, Brf.Site, Brf.Brief, PC.Class, PX.Article PXA, PX.Pagedex PXP, IVR.Article IVRA, IVR.Pagedex IVRP, SM.Article SMA, SM.Pagedex SMP
FROM people P
LEFT JOIN people_1_bio PB ON PB.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_1_class PC ON PC.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_briefs Brf ON Brf.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_articles_px PX ON PX.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_articles_ivr IVR ON IVR.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_articles_sm SM ON SM.URL = P.URL
WHERE P.URL LIKE :url AND P.Site = :site
GROUP BY Class',
array( ) );

$stm->execute( array( ':url'=> $MyURL, ':site' => $MySiteID ) );

while( $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) {

    // your loop here
```